# writing table from a list in R

Tags: r, syntax-error, xlsx

I have a SNP file and i want to count how many they in each column. while writing a table from the list it shows error as "arguments imply differing number of rows". I want a solution so that i can write the list into a table.
Please help me.
input file : [image file is added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TfMZJ.png)
input file contain 830 row and 210 column
**#1 R code**

```
require(gdata)
library(plyr)
df = read.xls ("jTest_file.xlsx", sheet = 1, header = TRUE)
combine = c()
for(i in 1:v){
    vec = count(df[,i])
    colnames(vec) <- c (colnames(df[i]),"freq")
    combine = c(combine,vec)
}
write.table(combine,file="test_output.xls",sep="\t",quote=FALSE,row.names =FALSE)
```

but there are some blank values in the input so i substitued the blank with XX so that the row number can be maintain but it does not worked.
**#2 R code**

```
require(gdata)
library(plyr)
df = read.xls ("jTest_file.xlsx", sheet = 1, header = TRUE)
combine = c()
for(i in 1:v){
    data=sub("^$", "XX", df[,i])
    vec = count(data)
    colnames(vec) <- c (colnames(df[i]),"freq")
    combine = c(combine,vec)
}
write.table(combine,file="test_output.xls",sep="\t",quote=FALSE,row.names =FALSE)
```

Comment: Can you show me what is the sample output you want?

Comment: Sample output : it should give in such a way that first column for the id and second column of frequency of particular SNP allele. In a xls file.                                                                                                 X1005 freq X1006 freq.1 X1007 freq.2 X1008 freq.3
 23  138  17  19
A 591 C 1306 C 264 C 777
G 1128 T 296 C/T 45 T 934
G/A 48 T/C 50 T 1464 T/C 60

Comment: In `for(i in 1:v)` - what is `v`?

Comment: @jacob    v is the number of column in df.                                                                                                           df = read.xls ("jTest_file.xlsx", sheet = 1, header = TRUE)                                                                                                     v <- length(colnames(df))
combine = c()
for(i in 5:v){
 data=sub("^$", "XX", df[,i])
 vec = count(data)
 #vec = count(df[,i])
 colnames(vec) <- c (colnames(df[i]),"freq")
 combine = c(combine,vec)
}
write.table(combine,file="test_output.xls",sep="\t",quote=FALSE,row.names =FALSE)

Comment: for(i in 1:v)  can be written as for(i in 1: length(colnames(df))).

Answer (score 0):

There is a much cleaner way to do these counts using the `dplyr` and `tidyr` packages.

Since you did not provide sample data, I will make some first:

```
#Make sample data
li = lapply(1:10, function(X) {
    sample(x = c("A", "C", "G", "T"), size = 10, 
           replace = TRUE)
    })
df = data.frame(li, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
names(df) = paste("X", 1:10, sep = "")

head(df, 3)    
#   X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10
# 1  T  G  C  T  C  A  T  T  C   T
# 2  A  A  A  G  G  G  T  G  C   A
# 3  C  C  A  T  A  A  C  A  T   G
```

Now the actual answer - doing the counts:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
df_long = gather(df, var, value)
df_groups = group_by(df_long, var, value)
df_counts = summarise(df_groups, count = n())
df_wide = spread(df_counts, value, count, fill = 0)

df_wide    
# Source: local data frame [10 x 5]
# Groups: var [10]
# 
#      var     A     C     G     T
# *  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     X1     3     4     0     3
# 2    X10     5     0     2     3
# 3     X2     3     2     2     3
# 4     X3     4     3     1     2
# 5     X4     2     1     4     3
# 6     X5     2     3     3     2
# 7     X6     4     2     1     3
# 8     X7     2     4     2     2
# 9     X8     2     3     2     3
# 10    X9     2     2     2     4
```

I encourage you to explore individual steps (`df_long`, `df_groups`, `df_counts`, `df_wide`). This will give you a sense of what is going on with the data.